# Searching text by descending keyword match

Tags: hibernate-search

I have a keyword that I'm going to search, for example APPLE, but the result must be returned in descending matching of the keyword, for instance first of all it will return all the rows that matches APPLE, then APPL, APP, AP, A.

Comment: What is your actual question? Have you tried something? Mind you also a keyword search is a full word/token match. You are talking about wildcard matches. To achieve what you are asking you would have to index each word with different suffix length.

Comment: Sorry for long response, I have tried simple JPQL like clause, but I want to use Hibernate Search instead, may be someone have faced with similiar problem?